# Recursively Count Primes by 10,000

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple code to list primes between 1-1,000,000 but I'm using Eclipse IDE and it will only list up to 50,000 - anything higher terminates the console.

I've written code that works up to 50,000 but anything higher and the console terminates before it's done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;

    String primes = "";
    for(i=1;i<=50000;i++) { //this is where I limit the count
        int counter = 0;

        for(num=i;num>=1;num--) {
            if(i%num == 0) {
                counter = counter+1;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 2) {
            primes = primes + i + " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(primes);

}
```

This code will list the primes up to 50,000 but I need to reach a million. I was wondering if I could add a recursive step to do the next 50,000 and so on until the console lists all the primes between 1-1,000,000.

Comment: You're probably better off writing to a text file instead of outputting to the console, regardless of whether or not you can print all of it to the console

Comment: i am definitely no expert on this matter, but i doubt recursion will increase the result of your output, if anything it would probably worsen it, but that's entirely my opinion

Comment: You are having issues printing a lot because you are printing literally every on a _single_ line.

Comment: Your code seems correct, its just consol is not working for large output string maybe, try online compiler

Comment: If your objective is to print every prime, then just print the prime inside the `if (counter == 2)` block instead of appending it to the string.

Comment: For the record, even if you could print every single prime on a single line, this would take absolutely forever to compute. Take a look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes or another more efficient prime-finding algorithm if you want to find all the primes.

Answer (score 0):

I think people are missing the point on why it is not printing to the console.  You can print every prime under 1 million just fine, just not *all* on a single line.  Instead you can print them each on a new line with this modification:

```
if(counter == 2) {
    primes = i + " ";
}
```

Note that you are no longer appending the `primes` into the same `String`.  Now you also need to move the `System.out.println(primes);` into the `for` loop and `if` statement to print each iteration.

Afterward you are free to change the loop to `i <= 1000000` and it will continuously print every prime until 1 million hits.

Here is the complete code with modifications to make it completely clear:

```
int i = 0;
int num = 0;

String primes = "";
for (i = 1; i <= 1_000_000; i++) { //this is where I limit the count
    int counter = 0;

    for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
        if (i % num == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 2) {
        primes = i + " ";
        System.out.println(primes);
    }   
}
```

**Note:**  As some comments pointed out, if you actually need to *use* this information it is obviously much more useful outputting to a file, but I assume this some sort of assignment or just for practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Eclipse console properties, but you can use String builder instead and print numbers in a line only if the length acceptable for console. You could experiment with this value and choose that number of characters that you're able to print in console output.

```
    StringBuilder primes = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) { //this is where I limit the count
        int counter = 0;

        for (int num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
            if (i % num == 0) {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 2) {
            primes.append(i).append(" ");

            if (primes.toString().length() >= 500) {
                System.out.println(primes);
                primes.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(primes);
```